# Display in Anaconda iPython console messed up

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, qtconsole

I use Anaconda 1.9.1 python QT console (python 2.7.6). I just installed in on a new desktop and noticed that the font displayed in the console are in very low resolution. In other words, when I type in the console, the font edges are not "round" anymore but appear very pixelated. This does not happen on the old desktop that runs the same system.

Any ideas how to fix this? I would appreciate very much.

Comment: Would you mind providing details of your OS version, desktop environment, Qt version... If you launch ipython qtconsole from a terminal, are any warnings printed?

Comment: I use Windows 7, and the QT version that comes packaged with Anaconda 1.9.1

Comment: Also, no warnings get printed when I start the QT console session

Comment: I'm afraid Windows is outside my realm. You could try upgrading anaconda (2.0.1 is out - use conda to do this), since they Qt backend reverted to pyqt4 from pyside, and might just help you.

Comment: Yes, try `conda update anaconda` in a cmd shell (or `!conda update anaconda` in IPython) and see if that fixes it.